# No se visualizan las graficas de pandas en Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

Acabo de descargar el **Anaconda** y estoy probando el **Jupyter LAB**, hice algunas pruebas de gráficos con un dataframe y funciono sin problema, pero al hacer una segunda prueba se queda asi y no pasa absolutamente nada luego, se queda todo en negro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo:

```
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,3,2], b=[3,2,1]))
fig = df.plot()
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas incluir la directiva

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Justo debajo del import de Pandas, o arriba, da igual, pero el estándar es justo debajo de los imports en la primera celda

Comment: No me ha funcionado, sigue igual. En el notebook pasa lo mismo

Comment: ¿Podrías poner tu código como texto y no como imagen?

Comment: El codigo lo copié de la documentacion de Pandas, no sé por que habria de dar error

Comment: Si, era solo para no tener que escribirlo. Tu código me funciona perfectamente, solo comenté la línea de `pd.options...` porque no tengo `plotly` instalado, y de hecho, no lo necesitas. El `fig.show()` tampoco es necesario dentro de un notebook